# Ruby/Rails sort_by date desc, name asc

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a list page of two different classes and I'd like to sort them by date desc, name asc. Both have datetime fields with a date method in each model.

```
posts = Post.all
news = News.all
@news_and_posts = posts.zip(news).compact.select(&:date).sort {|x| [-x.date, x.name]}
```

This throws a NoMethodError:
undefined method `-@' for Tue, 11 Nov 2014:Date

On several other questions this answer was given within both sort_by and sort, but I'm not having any luck.

Rails 4.0.5
Ruby 2.1.3

Comment: You really should be doing this entirely using the model layer. There's also no such thing as a "negative date". If you need reverse order, add `.reverse` at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure where the "date" method exists in your data structures. Could you update with some examples? What are the data structures you start with, and what do you want in the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple things. First, you should use `sort_by` in your example above, because the block takes one parameter as you used. The `sort` block takes two - item A and item B, for comparison. Next, you can get what you want by subtracting the date from something significant, like today's date:

```
objects.sort_by {|x| [Date.today - x.date, x.name]}
```

Even if dates might be in the future, the math will still work.

These pages detail the difference between `sort` and `sort_by`:

http://rubycuts.com/enum-sort

http://rubycuts.com/enum-sort-by

Btw, I agree with other commenters that you really should be ordering these records in your database query itself, but I wanted to solve the specific problem you asked about.

Comment: Alternatively you could use sort and swap the comparisons to get them sorted the correct way: .sort {|a, b| a.date <=> b} or .sort {|a, b| b.date <=> a.date}

Comment: That wouldn't sort by *both* attributes, though. The sort_by I provided is the simplest way to sort by both (date descending, name ascending) as requested.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, that did the trick! I agree with commenters this won't be a permanent solution.

Comment: `Date.today - x.date` – clever. Thanks!